# Update PHP Variable after Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I am making an Ajax call to a PHP file that checks a condition and runs a query a MySQL query if the conditions are met.

The query updates a table in my DB with a new value. This all works great. I would like to know how to show the new value in the current page without having to manually reload. Code is Below.

The variable I am updating is **$trialExpiry**

**HTML/PHP**

```
<h4 class="sbText mt-10">Trial End Date: <?php echo date("d/m/Y",
                        strtotime($trialExpiry)); ?></h4>

<form id='promocode'>
     <input type='text' class='sbInput' placeholder='Promo Code' name='promocode'>
     <input type='hidden' name='userid' value='<?php echo $userID; ?>'>
     <button class='btn sbSubmit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   <script>
         $(function () {
             $('#promocode').on('submit', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                     type: 'post',
                     url: '../model/process-promo-code.php',
                     data: $('#promocode').serialize(),
                     success: function () {
                          $("button.btn").css({
                             'transition-duration': '1000ms',
                              'opacity': '0.5'
                           });
                     }
                 });
            });
      });
   </script>
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: What kind of "new value" do you want to show on your page? Please include that in your question: it is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do the live updating with PHP variables, since those are only refreshed when the page is reloaded. Instead, you want to update an element's value via AJAX. As far as I can tell, you want to update the expiration date. If you don't, just let me know and I can change the code to whatever it's supposed to do.

Here's the "control flow" of this functionality:

1. (Entry point) User clicks 'Submit', jQuery event handler fires
2. jQuery AJAX function is called and sends the promo code to a PHP script
3. In the PHP script, the database is updated with the promo code.
4. The PHP script returns the new expiry date (I'll assume that it's in the d/m/Y format you wanted)
5. The callback in the jQuery AJAX function receives the data from the script.
6. The callback's function body updates the "Expiry" element on the page with the value from the PHP call.

Here's how to put that into HTML / JavaScript:

```
<h4 class="sbText mt-10" id="expiry_label">
    Trial End Date: <?php echo date("d/m/Y",
                    strtotime($trialExpiry)); // The initial value can be displayed as normal. ?>
</h4>

<form id='promocode'>
     <input type='text' class='sbInput' placeholder='Promo Code' name='promocode'>
     <input type='hidden' name='userid' value='<?php echo $userID; ?>'>
     <button class='btn sbSubmit'>Submit</button>
</form>

 <script>
     $(function () {
         $('#promocode').on('submit', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: '../model/process-promo-code.php',
                 data: $('#promocode').serialize(),
                 success: function (result) {
                      $("button.btn").css({
                         'transition-duration': '1000ms',
                          'opacity': '0.5'
                       });
                       document.getElementById("expiry_label").innerHTML = "Trial End Date: " + result;
                 }
             });
        });
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, I only added an "id" attribute to the  element, a parameter to the "success" property of the AJAX call, and a line of code to update the  element.

Hope I helped!

Comment: This has helped a LOT! Thank You! I am struggling with one thing, the "result" is basically the entire html. How do I get it to just return the variable I need? Sorry to ask again.

Comment: Sorry I figured this out by myself. I was being dumb. Thanks so much, your answer is the "Answer". Thanks to the other folks who pitched in too.

Comment: @Lyrical.me The result is what the PHP script echoes. I don't know how yours works, but I was assuming that it returns an expiration date. If your script doesn't do that, then all you have to do is create a new PHP script that does that, run the AJAX function with that new script, and then call the old one afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a callback --  IE

```
 <script>
         $(function () {
             $('#promocode').on('submit', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                     type: 'post',
                     url: '../model/process-promo-code.php',
                     data: $('#promocode').serialize(),
                     success: function (data) {  //<----  CALLBACK


                             alert(data); // data contains the return from the ajax call

                          $("button.btn").css({
                             'transition-duration': '1000ms',
                              'opacity': '0.5'
                           });
                     }
                 });
            });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will help me on my way - I hope lol. The alert is displaying the HTML for my entire page.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to answer @zak

Answer (score 0):

Only change the success function like below

```
  success: function (data) {  //<----  CALLBACK


                             $('input["name='userid' "]').val(data); // data contains the return from the ajax call

                          $("button.btn").css({
                             'transition-duration': '1000ms',
                              'opacity': '0.5'
```

Comment: Here the code depend on the answer of Zak only one thing I change wich is I add val function to change the value of input field depending on it's name